# Greatest Prime Factor

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to complete an [algorithm challenge to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3). I'm not necessarily asking for the answer. Just trying to figure out why this code isn't working. Why does it return 'undefined' instead of a number?

```
let isPrime = n => {
    let div = n - 1;
    while (div > 1) {
        if (n % div == 0) return false;
        div--;
    }
    return true;
};

let primeFactor = x => {
    for (let i = Math.floor(x / 2); i > 1; i--) {
        if (x % i == 0 && isPrime(i) == true) {
            return i;
        }
    }
};

console.log(primeFactor(35)); // 7
console.log(primeFactor(13195)); // 29
console.log(primeFactor(600851475143)); // undefined
```

Comment: Where are you running your code?

Comment: I posted it on JSBin

Comment: It's been running for 5 minutes in my local copy of Node.js and it hasn't finished yet. I presume a browser implementation may just trigger a *this script is not responding* dialog.

Comment: @tyl-er I was responding to a question the other day that used JSBin and for some reason their script recieved inconsistent answers, I suggest you try another service, besides that, a loop from 300000000000 to 1 is going to take a long time but should work, I suggest you change your method

Comment: Oh wow. I guess for loops can't handle large numbers like that in Javascript. At least not quickly.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm newish to programming. I looked at the question you linked to. Do you mind explain how that relates to my question?

Comment: @NickA: Ah, you're right, it's just 40 bits in this case.

Comment: @tyl-er basically numbers over 2,147,483,647 will fail. (this is the largest possible value to my knowledge) Maybe you could amend your code so that it re-iterates 300 times maybe (as yours is ~300 times this value - 600,851,475,143 vs 2,147,483,647)?

Comment: A fair few of these coding challenges are about efficiency, and the massive numbers are testing that.

Comment: @RachelGallen no, JS will work up to 9 007 199 254 740 992

Comment: Not sure about what role `2,147,483,647` plays. `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `9,007,199,254,740,991`.

Comment: @RachelGallen: The mantissa is 53 bits, 2147483647, can be represented in just 31.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález but  I meant 2,147,483,647 for a max floating point value, not a safe integer

Comment: @JörgWMittag i only saw your comment now. Wow that's huge!

Comment: @RachelGallen: the max floating point value is roughly 18000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, 3.402823 x 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000  (or 3.402823 x 10 to the power of one hundred undecillion

Comment: So would you say as a general rule avoid using for loops for numbers over 2 billion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let primeFactor = x => {
    if (x === 1 || x === 2) {
        return x;
    }

    while (x % 2 === 0) {
        x /= 2;
    }
    
    if (x === 1) {
        return 2;
    }

    let max = 0;
    for (let i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i += 2) {
        while (x % i === 0) {
            x /= i;
            max = Math.max(i, max);
        }
    }

    if (x > 2) {
        max = Math.max(x, max);
    }
    
    return max;
};

console.log(primeFactor(35));
console.log(primeFactor(13195));
console.log(primeFactor(27));
console.log(primeFactor(1024));
console.log(primeFactor(30974914));
console.log(primeFactor(600851475143));
```

## Optimizations

- Dividing the number by 2 until it's odd since no even number is prime.
- The iteration increment is `2` rather than `1` to skip all even numbers.
- The iteration stops at `sqrt(x)`. The explanation for that is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PDtgHhpCHo).

Comment: @arboreal84: As Nick pointed out, the answer doesn't answer, and as James pointed out, the algorithm is not correct. So, this only leaves an incorrect answer that doesn't actually attempt to answer. Why would downvoting that be wrong?

Comment: @arboreal84 I appreciate this answer. I kinda wanted to solve it for myself, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: Just for the record, the algorithm was corrected thanks to @James feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not your algorithm it is perfectly valid, check the below slightly modified algorithm, all I've done is replaced your starting point `Math.floor(x/2)` with a parameter that you can choose:

```js
let isPrime = n => {
        let div = n - 1;
    while (div > 1) {
        if (n % div == 0) return false;
        div--;
    }
    return true;
};

function primeFactor(x, n){
    for (let i = n; i > 1; i--) {
        if (x % i == 0 && isPrime(i) == true) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

console.log(primeFactor(35, 35));
console.log(primeFactor(13195, 13195));
console.log(primeFactor(600851475143, 100000))
```

Using the above you'll get an answer that proves your implementation works, but the loop is too big to do the entire thing(i.e. from `Math.floor(600851475143/2)`). Say your computer can do 500million loops per second, going through every one from 300,425,737,571 down to 1 would take 167 hours, even at 5 billion loops per second it would take 16 and a half hours. Your method is **extremely** inefficient but **will** return the correct answer.  The reason you're not getting an answer on JSBin is more likely to do with browser/service limitations.

---

### Spoilers on more efficient solution below

---

The following implementation uses a prime sieve([Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)) in order to generate any list of primes requested and then checks if they fully factor into the given number, as long as you use a large enough list of primes, this will work exactly as intended. it should be noted that because it generates a large list of primes it can take some time if ran incorrectly, a *single* list of primes should be generated and used for all calls below, and the cached list of primes will pay off eventually by having to perform less calculations later on:

```js
function genPrimes(n){
  primes = new Uint32Array(n+1);
  primes.fill(1)
  for(var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++){
    if(primes[i]){
      for(var j = 2*i; j < n; j+=i){
        primes[j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  primeVals = []
  for(var i = 2; i < primes.length; i++){
    if(primes[i]){
      primeVals.push(i);
    }
  }
  return primeVals;
}
    
function primeFactor(x, primes){
  var c = x < primes.length ? x : primes.length
  for (var i = c; i > 1; i--) {
    if(x % primes[i] == 0){
      return primes[i];
    }
  }
}

primes = genPrimes(15487457);
console.log(primeFactor(35, primes));
console.log(primeFactor(13195, primes));
console.log(primeFactor(600851475143, primes));
console.log(primeFactor(30974914,primes));
```

Comment: Thank's I learned a lot from that answer. So if this were a normal web app and we were using smaller numbers like 13195, would there still be a noticeable difference in efficiency?

Comment: @arboreal84 " as long as you use a large enough list of primes", generate more primes then

Comment: @tyl-er with numbers of that scale I wouldn't worry about efficiency unless you're running this code a great number of times

Comment: Rather than creating an empty array, you need to create an `Array` of size `n` and then fill it. The difference is the cost of array resizing.

Comment: Then, instead of using `Array` you can use `Uint32Array` which is much faster than `Array` for numbers. And instead of initializing the array with a for loop, use `Uint32Array.prototype.fill`. If you wish to still make it floats, you can use `Float64Array`.

Comment: @arboreal84 ah, I know I was missing something with the generating of the array, ta

Comment: @arboreal84 see the latest changes to the algorithm and explanation, I wasn't really explicit with where the efficiency comes from before

Comment: Yes, in the long run the memoization cost is amortized. It's a tradeoff. It all depends on the use case.